# Aweber API .NET SDK 401 unauthorized exception

Tags: c#, .net, api, aweber

I've followed the documentation steps and everything went smooth until step 5.

After successful authorization I've tried to access account data, like in step 5

```
var api = new API(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
api.OAuthToken = "My OAuthToken"; // That I've received on step 4
Account account = api.getAccount();
```

and I've got 401 exception on api.getAccount();

Please tell me what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. In order someone else has the same issue, here is fully functional code example

```
public class AWeber
    {
        public void Authorize()
        {
            var Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            var api = new API(AppSettings.AWebberConsumerKey, AppSettings.AWebberConsumerSecret);
            api.CallbackUrl = "http://localhost:61006/test.aspx"; 
            api.get_request_token();
            Session["OAuthToken"] = api.OAuthToken;
            Session["OAuthTokenSecret"] = api.OAuthTokenSecret;

            api.authorize();
        }

        public void InitAccessToken(string OAuthVerifier)
        {
            var Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            var api = new API(AppSettings.AWebberConsumerKey, AppSettings.AWebberConsumerSecret);
            api.OAuthToken = (string)Session["OAuthToken"];
            api.OAuthTokenSecret = (string)Session["OAuthTokenSecret"];
            api.OAuthVerifier = OAuthVerifier;

            // These two are final token that are needed
            Session["OAuthToken"] = api.get_access_token();
            Session["OAuthTokenSecret"] = api.adapter.OAuthTokenSecret;            
        }

        public void GetData()
        {
            var Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            var api = new API(AppSettings.AWebberConsumerKey, AppSettings.AWebberConsumerSecret);

            api.adapter.OAuthToken = (string)Session["OAuthToken"];
            api.adapter.OAuthTokenSecret = (string)Session["OAuthTokenSecret"];
            Account account = api.getAccount();       
        }
    }
```